# adjective and adverb clause

Tags: clauses

Please read the following sentences and my concern for them:

> 1) In 4Q 2013, Malaysia’s national house price index rose 8.1% year-on-year, a slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12.

Is this sentence correct? *A slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12,* is this an adjective phrase describing 8.1% ?

> 2) House prices in State A recorded the highest surge,grew 14.7% yoy.

Again, is the sentence correct? *Grew 14.7% yoy*, is this an adverb clause modifying the action surge?

Thanks for all the answers. Just to understand the sentence construction better, is (A slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12 ) an adjective phrase describing 8.1% ? Is (growing 14.7% year-on-year) an adverb phrase describing surge ?

Comment: The chunk starting *a slowdown* is not an adjective phrase but an [appositive](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/596/01/). The chunk *grew 14.7% yoy* is a VP with the same implicit subject as the first clause. It should be joined with *and*, not just a comma; or disjoined with a semicolon + a repetition of the subject (or *it*); or recast as a participle phrase *growing 14.7% yoy*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, StoneyB. By the way, what is VP ? Verb phrase ? I thought "grew 14.7% yoy" is a clause. Thanks again.

Comment: The term derives from 'verb phrase', but since that term is ambiguous most linguists today just use VP, pronounced VeePee. It is ordinarily the entire predicate, the verb with its complements and adjuncts. I don't call it a clause in this case because it is in effect the second of two conjoined VPs with a shared subject; the structure is [Subject + [VP1 + VP2]].

Answer (score 1):

> 1) In 4Q 2013, Malaysia’s national house price index rose 8.1% year-on-year, a slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12.

They are using a lot of technical terminology here. 4Q 2013 means quarter 4 of that year, which would be October to December of 2013. Year-on-year probably means year-over-year. I googled the meaning of "year-over-year" and it means the yearly average for every year since the index started. 4Q12 is the same thing again. It means quarter 4, which is October to December of 2012.

> 2) House prices in State A recorded the highest surge,grew 14.7% yoy.

Again, they are using very technical terminology. "yoy" is probably "year-over-year".

---

I would make the following corrections to the grammar:

> 1) In 4Q 2013, Malaysia’s national house price index rose 8.1% year-over-year, a slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12.

I changed year-on-year to year-over-year.

> 2) House prices in State A recorded the highest surge, growing 14.7% yoy.

I changed grew to growing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you are comparing 4Q 2013 vs 4Q 2012

2) House prices recorded an increase of 14,7%, the highest yoy. Or:

*House prices  recorded the highest increase by growing  14.7% yoy.*

Comment: With that respect "hike in prices" is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

1) is OK.

> 2) House prices in State A recorded the highest surge by growing 14.7% year-on-year.

or

> 2) House prices in State A recorded the highest surge, growing 14.7% year-on-year.

The meaning of *surge* is a sudden sharp increase, not quite the same as *increase* by itself.

Also, I think you should write out "year-on-year" and not abbreviate it. Haven't seen "yoy" before, unless its a specialized usage.

Comment: Thanks Josh61 and user3169. Just to understand the sentence construction better, is (A slowdown as compared to 12.2% registered in 4Q12 ) an adjective phrase describing 8.1% ? Is (growing 14.7% year-on-year) an adverb phrase describing surge ?

Comment: downvote comment, please.